# error: unable to find utility "git", not a developer tool or in PATH

Tags: git, xcode7.3

I have updated Xcode version to 7.3.1.when I use '`git status`',I find an error! as follow:

```
$git status
sh: line 1:  1601 Segmentation fault: 11  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -sdk / -find git 2> /dev/null
git: error: unable to find utility "git", not a developer tool or in PATH
```

Thank you advanced!

Comment: My Mac Opeation System version is OS X 10.11.5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best solution will be to download and install it - even that you assume it is already installed: https://git-scm.com/download/mac

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I have solved this problem in the way that you provided!

Comment: If you have Homebrew installed, you can install Git via the `brew install git` command. See here: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Getting-Started-Installing-Git

Comment: This is a workaround that doesn't fix the underlying problem -- that xcode for some reason fails to launch developer tools. It should not be the accepted answer. You will just run into the same problem with other developer tools.

Comment: well, at the time of the question (more than 3 years ago), it solved the problem for him so he accepted the answer.

Answer (score 97):

This happened to me also with upgrading to High Sierra and XCode to 9. This sequence has fixed it.

```
xcode-select --install
sudo xcode-select -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

Found this answer on https://davidwalsh.name/fix-git-high-sierra-upgrade
(article and comments.)

Comment: Thanks this is amazing! :)

Comment: This is the best answer because it requires no reboot or restart :)  Through many cycles of sleep/wake terminal can lose reference to command line tools.  If you already have xcode-select installed (as many do) just running the second line fixes this.

Answer (score 57):

I had this same problem -- I exited my bash session (closed the terminal) and started a new one and it fixed it.

Comment: THX...it's a weird problem

Comment: Same here, it would be the right answer, just the terminal lost the session.

Comment: This was useful for MacOS 10.13 and Xcode 9.3 (after reinstalling commandline tools)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue after upgrading to Big Sur. I fixed this issue by running the following command:

> `sudo xcode-select -switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`

P.S. I did not need to run this command: `xcode-select --install`

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had to uninstall and reinstall all my `brew` applications, as documented [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/344689/269654).

i.e.

```sh
brew list -1 > brew.txt # list out all installed packages
brew list -1 | xargs brew rm --force # remove all installed packages
brew install $(cat brew.txt | tr '\n' ' ') # install all previously installed packages
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the above solutions fixed the issue for me, I had to actually just restart my computer which fixed it. This was a weird bug.